How to interpret solution to Dirac equation for Hydrogen atom?
For the solution to the Dirac equation for the Hydrogen atom, for the case of spin-up $1S_{1/2}$, the solution has this proportionality equation:
$$\Psi \propto \begin{pmatrix}
(1+\gamma)r^{\gamma-1}e^{-Cr} \\
0 \\
iZ\alpha r^{\gamma-1}e^{-Cr} z/r \\
iZ\alpha r^{\gamma-1}e^{-Cr} (x+iy)/r
\end{pmatrix}$$
I understand that one of the entries will be equal to $0$ depending on the spin-orientation ($1S_{1/2}$ spin-down has a $0$ on the first entry). However, what physically do these non-zero entries mean and how can they be converted into something useful like radial probability values? Usually there is one value, usually a complex number, but here the solution suggests a real-valued number, an imaginary number and a complex number. Which of these are physically useful and what's the procedure for turning these into physically-important quantities?


what physically do these non-zero entries mean?

The solutions to the Dirac equation in the quoted Wikipedia article
are meant to be in the Dirac basis (also called standard representation),
although the article doesn't mention this explicitly.
In the Dirac basis the $4$ bispinor components are defined by
fermion/antifermion (labeled below as $+,-$)
and spin component $S_z$ ($\uparrow,\downarrow$):
$$\Psi=\begin{pmatrix}
\psi_{+\uparrow}\\
\psi_{+\downarrow} \\
\psi_{-\uparrow}\\
\psi_{-\downarrow}
\end{pmatrix}
\quad
\begin{align}
&\text{electron, spin up} \\
&\text{electron, spin down} \\
&\text{positron, spin up} \\
&\text{positron, spin down}
&\end{align}$$
Because for the hydrogen-like atom the third and fourth component
($\psi_{-\uparrow}$ and $\psi_{-\downarrow}$)
both contain the small factor $Z\alpha$,
these positron components are quite small, as it should be.

how can they be converted into something useful like radial probability values?

The probability density to find the particle
near position $\vec{r}$ as an electron or positron
with any spin direction is
$$\frac{dP}{d^3r} = \Psi^\dagger\cdot\Psi
=|\psi_{+\uparrow}|^2
+|\psi_{+\downarrow}|^2
+|\psi_{-\uparrow}|^2
+|\psi_{-\downarrow}|^2$$
This is always a positive real number as it should be.

Does this mean that the 4-vector should be normed for the physically significant solution or would just the entry relating to the type of particle examined be used?

@TCoff For extracting physical results you need the normed 4-spinor.
